# aws eb deployment error : No matching distribution found for anaconda-client==1.6.9

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am very new to AWS and in-general coding. I wrote a small Django application, and now I am trying to deploy it on AWS using elastic beanstalk with the help of this URL. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html

My application uses Postgres database for which I need  `psycopg2` package, which I have added in my requirements.txt file. (this is not part of the instructions on this URL but I knew I need psycopg2 so I added)

when I create EB environment using `eb create django-env`, I get the following error:

This log I took from EC2 `/var/log/`.

Here is the error:

> [2018-09-26T21:44:20.502Z] INFO  [3151]  - [Application deployment
>   app-d840-180926_224155@1/StartupStage0/AppDeployPreHo ok/03deploy.py]
>   : Starting activity... [2018-09-26T21:44:21.774Z] INFO  [3151]  -
>   [Application deployment
>   app-d840-180926_224155@1/StartupStage0/AppDeployPreHo ok/03deploy.py]
>   : Activity execution failed, because: Collecting alabaster==0.7.10
>   (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requi rements.txt (line 1))
>       Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2e/c3/9b7dcd8548cf2c00531763ba154e524af575e8f36701bacfe5bcadc674
>   40/alabaster-0.7.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl Collecting
>   anaconda-client==1.6.9 (from -r
>   /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 2))
>       Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement anaconda-client==1.6.9 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requi
>   rements.txt (line 2)) (from versions: 1.1.1, 1.2.2)   **No matching
>   distribution found for anaconda-client==1.6.9 (from -r
>   /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 2))**   **You are using
>   pip version 9.0.1, however version 18.0 is available.**   You should
>   consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
>   2018-09-26 21:44:21,768 ERROR    Error installing dependencies:
>   Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/
>   python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py", line 22, in main
>         install_dependencies()
>       File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py", line 18, in install_dependencies
>         check_call('%s install -r %s' % (os.path.join(APP_VIRTUAL_ENV, 'bin', 'pip'), requirements_file), shell=True)
>       File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 186, in check_call
>         raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)   CalledProcessError: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r
>   /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned  non-zero exit
>   status 1 (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)

My `settings.py` file of Django project has `psycopg2`

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'test',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
        'TEST': {
            'NAME': 'testdb',
        },
    }
}
```

[EDIT] My requirements.txt file is:

```
c:\Users\abhi\OneDrive\Python-Projects\myproject>cat requirements.txt
Django==2.1.1
psycopg2==2.7.5
pytz==2018.5
```

My question is:

1. How to fix this issue?
2. Why it is saying that **You are using pip version 9.0.1, however, version 18.0 is available?** I am using pip 18.0, I am sure.
3. Why it says - **Collecting anaconda-client==1.6.9** ? I want to install `psycopg2`, not `anaconda`.

It is my side project, and I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

Well, your `requirements.txt` lists `anaconda-client==1.6.9`. The only available versions of the same on PyPi are [1.1.1 and 1.2.2](https://pypi.org/project/anaconda-client/#history). [As far as the Github project](https://github.com/Anaconda-Platform/anaconda-client/releases) is concerned, 1.6.9 does indeed exist, however, PyPi/`pip` are not aware of it since it was never published to PyPi. Your options are:

1. to list anaconda-client 1.2.2/1.1.1 in requirements.txt
2. to install anaconda-client through `conda`
3. bundle the source code of `anaconda-client` into your project so that you can avoid having to install it altogether.

Comment: my requirements.txt file does not have anaconda-client==1.6.9 
and that's exactly what baffles me. (see edit in my question, I have added the txt)

Comment: Its a dependency of `alabaster`. I see this is not a dependency either, however, it might in turn be a dependency of something else. Does `pip install -r requirements.txt` work correctly on your local machine?

Comment: Well,
I am able to resolve this. 
I think the reason was that I did not commit after I changed by requirements.txt file. And eb create only takes code from the master branch. 
nevertheless, thank you very much.
My code is live on AWS now.

Comment: Glad that your code works. "`eb create` takes the latest commit of your present branch" is an accurate statement.